# c# mssql sql concatenation and multiple inserts

Tags: c#, sql

recently I faced a situation where I was shown code similar to the following:

```
string insertSql = "";
foreach (int animalType in new[] { 1,2,3 })
    insertSql += String.Format("INSERT INTO `animalType` (type) VALUES ({0}); ", animalType);
```

The number of inserts each time is small (1-3).

It feels "bad", but I cannot say why exactly. Any thoughts?

Basically many sql inserts are concatenated into a single string. Afaik there are 3 reasons not to add values to sql by string concatenations: security, formatting problems, speed of execution. Because the parameters are ints, there cannot be any sql injections. There are no formatting issues to deal with. Additionally because these are inserts the sql server will not reuse the handle (afaik it stores and optionally reuses query handles).

Additionally there are no triggers on the table.

Generally it could be improved by doing single insert with union `INSERT INTO animalType (type) (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3)`.

I know a data table could be used an added to a parametrized query or xml could be used but wouldnt it just make the code longer and harder to read?
I just don't have any real arguments against it.

And is there any point in dynamically creating parameterized query in such manner:

```
string insertSql = "";
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
var types = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };
for (int i = 0; i < types.Length; i++)
{
    insertSql += String.Format("INSERT INTO `animalType` (type) VALUES (@typeParam{0}); ", i);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("typeParam" + i, types[i]);
}
```

What can I say to a person concatenating sql integer values and not using parametrized queries because his method is simpler? :)

Comment: This might be more appropriate in codereview.SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is valid code that is acceptable in some cases. It is not optimal but there are no security issues. SQL Server usually auto-parameterizes simple queries like this one (because many developers do things like this...).

There are three relevant optimizations here:

- Saving round-trips. All the approaches you mention achieve this goal.
- Executing less statements. The `UNION ALL` and TVP proposals of yours accomplish this one. Each statement has some CPU overhead.
- Inserting more rows per statement so that the optimizer can craft a better plan. Same as the previous point.

Whether you like the simple approach or the faster, more complex approach is a trade-off that only you can make.

Answer (score 2):

You can profile it to be sure, but I'd bet you don't get *significantly* worse performance by just executing one command multiple times:

```
string insertSql = "INSERT INTO animalType (type) VALUES (@type)";
var types = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };
using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(insertSql, conn))
{
    foreach(var type in types)
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", type);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

}
```

> What can I say to a person concatenating sql integer values and not using parametrized queries because his method is simpler?

My argument would be that it wouldn't take much to make the code vulnerable to SQL Injection and formatting issues.  The instant you add a string column the code is vulnerable, and chances are the next person to come around that adds the string column is not going to take the time to convert the query to parameterized just to add one column.

Comment: This adds one round-trip per insert. If the round-trip is 1ms and the insert is 0.25ms it adds 4x overhead.

Comment: @usr which may not have any significant impact to the overall performance of the app.